# How to cast the return value of a getter

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap called map as a member, and I retrieve values from it using:

```
public Object get(String s) {
  return this.map.get(s);
}
```

I think I can turn this into something using generics so we can cast the return value inline, something like this:

```
public V get(String s) {
  return (V)this.map.get(s);
}
```

but that doesn't compile. Basically, instead of doing this:

```
var t = (Zoom)x.get("foo");
```

it might be nice to use:

```
var t = x.<Zoom>get("foo")
```

but I am not sure if something like this possible.

Comment: What is the map definition ? what Type is there in ?

Comment: the map field/member is just like so `public final HashMap<String, Object> map;`

Comment: Why is your value type `Object`?  And not a generic?

Comment: @JoeC well I am trying to make it generic, aren't I? I don't quite understand

Comment: By generic, I mean in the Java sense (i.e. `HashMap<String,V>`).

Comment: @JoeC yes that's what I was trying to do, I figured it out after I posted, see my answer

Comment: Have a concrete object, instead of `Map<String, Object>`, the interface already has generic implementation `<K,V>` just binding it to better types would help.

Answer (score 1):

You should be making your `HashMap` generic as well by making the entire class generic:

```
class MyClass<V> {
    private Map<String, V> map = new HashMap<>();

    public V get(String s) {
        return this.map.get(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted, but in my case not all types in the map will be of type V, the values in the map could be anything, so V is just Object here

Comment: Do the types share a common supertype other than Object? If so, make the definition `MyClass<V extends SomeSuperType>` and make your final cast *outside* this code

Comment: They *don't* share a common super type other than Object

Comment: @MrCholo If they don't share a common type, do all objects actually need to be in the same map? Your examples look like you have to know the type of the value for each key anyway, so maybe you could simply store them in different maps for type safety

Comment: @MrCholo: if they don't share a super type, what is the collection about? What do you name it? Is it "any objects I want to keep for later use" or "my globally accessible object collection"? Think of this: do you store all your objects, e.g. butter and your clothes all in the same place, e.g. the oven and then you call them by their name to get them? That's what you have implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh I think this works:

```
public <V> V get(String s) {
  return (V)this.map.get(s);
}
```

of course I do get this warning:

[image]

Comment: As long as the map is `<String, Object>`, I think this is bad design.

Comment: Ok, if it's a bad design, how do I improve it? That's why I posted the OP, for advice more than anything

Answer (score 0):

You could also pass the generic type down to the HashMap member on creation and retreive the correct type without a cast.

```
class ClassUsingHashMap<T>{
    private HashMap<String, T> map = new HashMap<String, T>()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the type of values beforehand, you could pass type information with a `Class` object:

```
public class MapContainer {
    private Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

    public <V> V get(String s, Class<V> classOfValue) {
        Object value = this.map.get(s);
        return classOfValue.cast(value);
    }
}
```

And then just do

```
Integer intValue = container.get("key", Integer.class);
```

But this will explode with a `ClassCastException` if the value stored by "key" is not an `Integer`, so you would have to be very careful.

But if you know the value type beforehand, it's just

```
public class MapContainer<T> {
    private Map<String, T> map = new HashMap<>();

    public T get(String s) {
        return this.map.get(s);
    }
}
```